Trouble installing the package MultipleZetaValues
I have tried to install the package MultipleZetaValues using
PacletInstall[CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/pisco125/MultipleZetaValues-1.2.0.paclet"]]
but only got

$Failed

Can you please help with this?

Where did you get this link from? It looks like it is not publicly accessible ...

@Domen : I got this from the beginning of this answer by Jorge Zuniga.

As mentioned in the articles by the author of the package (e.g. arXiv:2201.01676), the package can be downloaded from the corresponding ResearchGate website. There is an installation guide with two methods. Method 1 (installing directly from the author's Wolfram Cloud) is not working due to changed permissions of the cloud file, so you have to use Method 2. However, when uploading the .paclet file to ResearchGate, they probably replaced the .paclet extension with .zip. Therefore, you have to first download the Mathematica_package_MultipleZetaValues.zip file, then manually rename it to Mathematica_package_MultipleZetaValues.paclet, and finally use PacletInstall["path-to-file/Mathematica_package_MultipleZetaValues.paclet"]. I've tried it myself and it works.

Thank you for your answer. I tried that, too. However, the installation guide suggests PacletInstall@
FileNameJoin[{"C:", "foldername1", "foldername2", "foldername3",
"MultipleZetaValues-1.2.0.paclet"}], whereas there is no file MultipleZetaValues-1.2.0.paclet in the package. There is the file MultipleZetaValues.m there, but it is encoded.

@IosifPinelis, thanks for your feedback! I haven't tested it before, so now I've updated my answer with the correct instructions. I hope it works now! :)

Thank you very much for your help!
